# Pandas `value_counts()` and `unique()` result in different category orders

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

For a given column, `value_counts()` function of pandas counts the number of occurrences of each value that this column takes. On the other hand, `unique()` function returns the unique values that occur at least once.

Now, just to given an example, take the `mushroom` dataset in the [UCI Repository](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/mushroom).

When I list the unique values in a particular column

```
df["class"].unique()
```

I get the output:

```
array(['p', 'e'], dtype=object)
```

However, when I count the number of occurrences

```
df["class"].value_counts()
```

I get the output:

```
e    4208
p    3916
Name: class, dtype: int64
```

Here, we can observe that the orders of the categories are different. The first one starts with `'p'`, whereas the second one starts with `'e'`. I do not understand why there is such a mismatch, as one would typically assume the same order for consistency. I am wondering if there is any explanation for this, and whether there is a good practice to fix this. What comes to mind initially is that, I can count the occurrences by `value_counts()` and then instead of using the `unique()` function I can take the indices of the result. Namely:

```
val_counts = df["class"].value_counts()
val_unique = np.array(val_counts.index)
val_unique
```

Output:

```
array(['e', 'p'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: @piRSquared Very interesting! rchson's answer proposes a way to retrieve the original value counts back. However, for complexity reasons, I would be more interested in using value_counts without sorting it at all. Are you aware of something that does this?

Comment: If you dont want to sort it at all, use .agg or .groupby on the size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pd.unique`, `np.unique`, `value_counts` and `groupby` all have slightly different ordering rules. You can choose the one you want in order to get the desired ordering

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'class': ['z', 'z', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'a', 'f', 'f']})
```

---

#### `pd.unique`

does not sort, output is ordered by first appearance

```
df['class'].unique()
#array(['z', 'a', 'f'], dtype=object)
```

#### `np.unique`

sorts the values

```
np.unique(df['class'])
#array(['a', 'f', 'z'], dtype=object)
```

#### `value_counts`

sorts on descending counts by default, can toggle to occurrence based

```
df['class'].value_counts()
#f    5
#a    4
#z    2
#Name: class, dtype: int64

df['class'].value_counts(sort=False)
#z    2
#a    4
#f    5
#Name: class, dtype: int64
```

#### `groupby` + `size`

sorts based on label, can be toggled to sort based on label occurrence

```
# Sorts output based on grouping keys (i.e. labels)
df.groupby('class').size()
#class
#a    4
#f    5
#z    2
#dtype: int64

# Output ordered by occurrence of grouping keys
df.groupby('class', sort=False).size()
#class
#z    2
#a    4
#f    5
#dtype: int64
```

In your case, you want either `value_counts` with `sort=False`, or  `groupby` + `size` with `sort=False`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried `sort = True` and I still get different orders from `unique()`. So it looks like although we exclude a post-processing (sorting) step, the initial orders may still differ from the `unique` function.

Comment: @independentvariable `sort=True` for which function? `pd.unique` is guaranteed to have the output with _Uniques are returned in order of appearance. This does NOT sort_. So anything that does sort would possibly differ. That's why the only ouputs that match are the functions where `sort=False` is explicitly stated.

Comment: I am so sorry, I meant `sort = False` still results in different orders than `unique`.

Answer (score 1):

`value_counts()` sorts by the counts by default. You can simply call

```
df['class'].value_counts().loc[df['class'].unique()]
```

to rearrange it back to the ordering from `.unique()`